# FullCalendar: refetchEvents call causes to all meetings to blink during re-rendering

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I play with fullCalendar and I use [refetchEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

It works properly and this command calls `events` method with callback

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { /* ... */ }
```

however it first **remove** all meetings from calendar and after  - renders new ones. This approach causes to all table to *blink* (different from google behaviour).

Is there any other way to render meetings without *clear-add*?

---

Seems like I need to add only deltas that makes work too hard, messy and not stable

Thanks,

Comment: I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t29p9c9x/1/) to reproduce the problem, will post an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to do the ajax request first (where you initially put `.fullCalendar('refetchEvents')`), and if it succeeds, then call refetchevents. The code will look something like this:

```
var events = [];
$.get('/events/get', function(result){
    events = result;
});    
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        callback(events);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good catch, ill try it out. I use angular so will store everything in Service/Factory

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your ajax parameter :

```
async:false,

$.ajax({
    url: calendar_url + '&start'+start.unix()+'&end='+end.unix(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async:false,
    success: function(response) {
   }
})
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code to the OP understand why he it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach instead of refetchEvents so it's not blinking.

```
var events = {
                 url: '/getEVents',
                 type: 'GET',
             }
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
```